# How to get bindings with datatype using Laravel 5.*

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i'm trying to make a subquery something like

```
SELECT COUNT (*) as total_count FROM ($sql) as count_table
```

here the method:

```
public function getTotal($query = null)
    {
        if (is_null($query)) {
            return $this->total;
        }

        $sql = $query->toSql();

        $bindings = $query->getBindings();

        foreach ($bindings as $binding) {
            $bind = gettype($binding) === '' ? "'" . $binding . "'" : $binding; //is not working as expected
            $sql = preg_replace('/\?/', $bind, $sql, 1);
        }

        dd($sql);

        $sql = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $sql);

        $total = \DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select(\DB::raw("select count(*) as total_count from ($sql) as count_table"));

        return $total[0]->total_count;
    }
```

the problem is when i preg_replace all ? in the sql query i get only the values without the datatype.

my getBindings():

```
array:14 [▼
  0 => 0
  1 => "D"
  2 => 0
  3 => 0
  4 => "CZ"
  5 => "00000"
  6 => "15000"
  7 => "D"
  8 => 0
  9 => 0
  10 => 0
  11 => "AT"
  12 => "0000"
  13 => "2000"
]
```

in this array i have some integers and strings and i would like to bind exact the same datatypes.

i have tried to check the strings with gettype() but this is not working.

Comment: UPDATE: i got it: `$bind = is_string($binding) ? "'" . $binding . "'" : $binding;`

Comment: Are you really unparameterizing a query here?   This is not the way to handle a query builder object...

Comment: i don't understand. can you explain ? I need to this to make a custom pagination because laravel don't handle it for sql union. If you have a better idea pls let me know

Comment: You're removing the parameters and putting the variables directly in the query, voiding the SQL injection protection provided by the Query Builder / prepared statements.

Comment: okey so how can i make a subquery with bindings without putting it directly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel 5.6.12, the `fromSub()` function was added to the query builder that does what you're trying to do.

Untested, but I think your function would look something like:

```
public function getTotal($query = null)
{
    if (is_null($query)) {
        return $this->total;
    }

    return \DB::connection('sqlsrv')
        ->selectRaw('count(*) as total_count')
        ->fromSub($query)
        ->value('total_count');
}
```

If you're not on 5.6.12 yet, your specific query could be handled wholly using the `selectRaw` statement, which takes bindings as the second parameter. In this case, your function would look something like:

```
public function getTotal($query = null)
{
    if (is_null($query)) {
        return $this->total;
    }

    return \DB::connection('sqlsrv')
        ->selectRaw('count(*) as total_count from ('.$query->toSql().') as count_table', $query->getBindings())
        ->value('total_count');
}
```

---

Note: if you haven't seen it before, the `value()` function executes the query, takes the first row, and then gets the value of the specified column from that first row. Just a little cleaner than using `get()` or `first()` and then accessing the property.